# FTP Server Rejecting Local Domain

Tags: iis, ftp

I attempted to map an ftp address to a network drive to make publishing builds a bit easier. When doing this the computer became incredibly unresponsive and the new mapped folder wouldn't open so I removed it. Since this any computer within my work domain has been unable to connect to this ftp server but devices outside of it connect without issue.

At what end would the issue be with this and how do I go about allowing devices from my work domain to connect to this ftp server again?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was caused by the IpSwitch FTP server we have blacklisting our own domain. It does expire after 1 day but can be deleted immediately via the admin portal.